# replace single slash with double slash, php

Tags: php

how replace single slash with double slash?
I have this text:

```
"/data/folder/"

 and i need get

"//data//folder//"
```

i try with replace, but get error:

```
$data = str_replace("\", "\\", $data);
```

Comment: What error do you get? Why are you using backslashes when what you want to replace is slashes?

Comment: Why do you need that replace?

Answer (score 7):

You're talking about backslashes or normal slashes ? anyway check the code below for both of them :

```
$str = '\dada\dsadsa';
var_dump(str_replace('\\', '\\\\', $str));
$str = '/dada/dadda';
var_dump(str_replace('/', '//', $str));
```

Answer (score 6):

You want to replace forward slash but your `str_replace` is having back slash.

Try:

```
$data = str_replace("/", "//", $data);
```

Cause of error:

`\` is used escaping. So the `\` in `"\"` is actually escaping the second `"`.

Answer (score 4):

Regarding why you are getting an error, backslashes are escape characters in strings wrapped in double quotes `"`. You need to escape them as well:

```
str_replace("\\", "\\\\", $data);
```

from what you are saying, you however probably want to use slashes, not backslashes, as shown by @codaddict.

Answer (score -1):

It is possible using following code:

```
<?php  $str = addcslashes("Hello World!","W");?>  
<?php echo $str;?> <br/>    
<?php $str2 = addcslashes($str,"W");     
echo $str2;        
?>
```

Comment: It is possible using following code..

<?php  $str = addcslashes("Hello World!","W");?><?php echo $str;?> <br/>
<?php $str2 = addcslashes($str,"W");
 echo $str2;
    ?>