# php regex replace double backslash with single

Tags: php, regex, backslash

I do not want to use `stripslashes()` because I only want to replace "\\" with "\".

I tried `preg_replace("/\\\\/", "\\", '2\\sin(\\pi s)\\Gamma(s)\\zeta(s) = i\\oint_C  \\frac{-x^{s-1}}{e^x -1} \\mathrm{d}x');`

Which to my disapointment returns: `2\\sin(\\pi s)\\Gamma(s)\\zeta(s) = i\\oint_C  \\frac{-x^{s-1}}{e^x -1} \\mathrm{d}x`

Various online regex testers indicate that the above should work. Why is it not?

Comment: what's your actual code? Are you doing `$a = preg_replace(...$a)` or are you only calling preg_replace without actually saving its result?

Comment: First of all: Try `preg_replace('/\\\\/', '\\', '2\\sin(...');`(single quotes). Then read up on `str_replace()`, egexes are the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: Can you use str_replace ('//', '/', $variable);

Comment: A related question (replace single \ with double \\): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5631946/replace-single-slash-with-double-slash-php

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First, like many other people are stating, regular expressions might be too heavy of a tool for the job, the solution you are using should work however.

```
$newstr = preg_replace('/\\\\/', '\\', $mystr);
```

Will give you the expected result, note that preg_replace returns a new string and does not modify the existing one in-place which may be what you are getting hung up on.

You can also use the less expensive str_replace in this case:

```
$newstr = str_replace('\\\\', '\\', $mystr);
```

This approach costs much less CPU time and memory since it doesn't need to compile a regular expression for a simple task such as this.

Answer (score 9):

You dont need to use regex for this, use

```
$newstr = str_replace("\\\\", "\\", $mystr);
```

See the [str_replace docs](http://php.net/manual/de/function.str-replace.php)

Comment: Your code will throw a parse error. It should be `$newqsstr = str_replace("\\\\", "\\", $mystr);`.

Comment: @SharanyaDutta Thanks, I must have miscopied the replace call. Edited that it. Sorry for the mistake!

Comment: @UliKöhler Simpler and better, right, because with regex `"/\\\\/"` you would match a single backslash, as the engine needs an escaped backslash to match a literal backslash, beause the  backslash has a [special meaning](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html) in regex. So it would be `"/\\\\{2}/"` to match a double backslash with a double-quoted str pattern.