# How to convert double backslash in string to one backslash in PHP?

Tags: php, string, laravel, str-replace

I need a to generate a string like this, `Helpers\Name`.

I have a `$prefix` that contains `\\` like `$prefix = "Helpers\\";`

When I merge the strings like below, It returns a string with double backslashes instead of one!

`$what_i_want = $prefix . 'Name'; // return Helpers\\Name`

After that result, I tried to replace the double backslashes by one with `str_repleca()` and `preg_replace()`methods but it does not work!

Any solution will be appreciated.

**Update:**
Here is my helper function in Laravel which I want to return what I want:

```
public static function getModelsClassesByString()
{
    $path = app_path();
    $models = [];
    $prefix = "App\\";
    $results = scandir($path);

    foreach ($results as $result) {
        if ($result === "." or $result === "..") continue;
        $filename = $prefix . $result;
        $models[] = substr($filename, 0, -4);
    }
    return $models;

}
```

the function return like below:

`["App\\Admin", "App\\User",...]`

Also, I really don't understand someone who could not help but let itself to destroy the question and my needs by down votes or destructor comments.

Comment: If you define `$prefix="Helpers\\"`, the string will only contain one backslash, if you define it `$prefix='Helpers\\'`, it will be two. So are you sure your string contains two backslashes?

Comment: You should try: `str_replace("\\\\", "\\", $prefix);`

Comment: _“It returns a string with double backslashes instead of one!”_ - no, it doesn’t!  https://3v4l.org/sneA8 proves that the code you have shown is not able to reproduce the problem. So please go read [ask] and [mcve], and then edit your question accordingly.

Comment: @CBroe, It's amazing! My code returns what I said. I'm using Laravel framework!

Comment: Well that’s why you should show us actual code that _does_ reproduce the problem! You have commented under several answers now that what was suggested there did “also not work” – but we still don’t have a proper example from you how you managed to get this wrong in the first place.

Comment: @CBroe I think it's not complicated to explain it in a complete example! I was surprised about this clear doing too!!!
But ok I will update the question to put my whole code in it.

Answer (score 1):

Another idea is not to include in your strings the \ character and concat it later.

Eg.

```
$prefix = "Helpers";
$what_i_want = $prefix ."\\". 'Name';
```

Result would be "Helpers\Name";

Answer (score 1):

You may try to make it simple like this, do not use double qoute.

```
public static function getModelsClassesByString()
{
    $path = app_path();
    $models = [];
    $prefix = "App" . '\\';
    $results = scandir($path);

    foreach ($results as $result) {
        if ($result === "." or $result === "..") continue;
        $filename = $prefix . $result;
        $models[] = substr($filename, 0, -4);
    }
    return $models;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try ([from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21076703/634120)):

```
$prefix = str_replace("\\\\", "\\", $prefix);
$what_i_want = $prefix . 'Name';
```

The reason is because backslashes are special characters so need to be escaped.

It will only work for two backslashes though and not varying amounts of occurrences.