# How to Replace special character backslash '\' with double back slash '\\' in a string using php?

Tags: php, replace, backslash

this is my sample string

```
$str = "The ADE/Op's.(\\localhost\corporateoffice\COMMERCIAL\EODB Feedback\EODBfeedbacklist.xls) are contacted personally and see that positive feedback  "
```

Comment: That's not a valid string.

Comment: @bassxzero Don't you mean `str_replace("\\","\\\\",$str)`?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude probably lol

Comment: by using this function ,str_replace("\\","\\\\",$str),its not replacing near string (\\localhost).current outpurt:\\10.10.10.202\\corporateoffice\\COMMERCIAL\\EODB Feedback\\EODBfeedbacklist.xls

Comment: Possible duplicate of [replace single slash with double slash, php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5631946/replace-single-slash-with-double-slash-php)

Comment: Looking at the code you shared, there isn't really any reason to use double quotes around your string, you could just wrap it in single quotes and escape Op\'s and it would be much less trouble.

Comment: In the string you show, there will be only *one* single back-slash, and that's the one between `(` and `localhost`. All the other slashes will be gone by the time it is stored in the variable `$str`. You need to have the double back-slashes *in the source file*.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

```
$var=str_replace('\\','\\\\',$str);
 echo $var;
```

Double backslash are to escape the character